# Interacting with Salesforce Public Solutions iFrame

Tags: knowledge, solutions

I'm currently implementing Public Solutions on an EE org, and trying to build any kind of "journey" up for end users. One of the key things I'm trying to get is, if the user cannot solve their problem with Solutions, they can submit a case to support, via web-to-case.

The trouble is the Public Solutions front is literally just an iFrame you drop onto your website and hope for the best.

So

```
<IFRAME title="Content" SRC="http://yyy.salesforce.com/sol/public/search.jsp?orgId=00Dxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Generates something like

[image: solutions]

And that's about as good (and indeed, as bad) as it gets. You have the option to include your own stylesheet (thankfully) but the experience, generally, is then very much governed by Salesforce, and is pretty limiting.

So my question would be, having put this iFrame on the website, and given the customer a reasonable chance to find a solution article - does anyone know of a way to redirect them on to a web-to-case form?

When viewing an article you get a pair of buttons at the bottom like this:

[image: solution helpful]

and I'd be happy to hijack the "No" button and turn that into a redirect to web-to-case, but I cannot for the life of me imagine how I would do that. **Can I get a Trigger on the "Self-service Answer Count" object/update** (and what could I do from there!?)? Or **is it possible to augment the action of the "No" button?**

Alternatively I would love to inject my own HTML/javascript sections somewhere on the Solutions page, but I can't find anyway to do that either? **Are there any "layout" settings for how a solution appears on the Public Solutions page**? (into which I can whack some useful formula field/markup)

Actually, any reassurance that Public Solutions is customisable beyond the bespoke CSS file you can provide would be more than welcome.